# Why source command is not working in crontab which uses shell script containing cd command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line

I made a script called `purging.sh`. I had used `cd` command in that script and the script changes directory many a times so that I have assigned some variable to the `cd` command which in turn help to change the directory.

```
cd /home/parthipan/test/wireshark/$a/$b
```

To run the script, I have to use `source ./purging.sh` or `. ./purging.sh`.

But I have to schedule the script for that I am using crontab,

```
10 01 * * * . /home/parthipan/test/purging.sh
```

Start of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$( date -d "`date` -60 days" "+%Y%m%d" | cut -b 1-4 )
b=$( date -d "`date` -60 days" "+%Y%m%d" | cut -b 5-6 )
c=$( date -d "`date` -60 days" "+%Y%m%d" | cut -b 7-8 )
cd /home/parthipan/test/wireshark/$a/$b
d=$( ll | awk -F " " '{print $9}' | awk -v value=$c '$1 < value' | sed "/^$/d" | xargs )
echo "The Days archiving are: $d"
e=$( ll | awk -F " " '{print $9}' | awk -v value=$c '$1 < value' | sed "/^$/d" | wc -l )
f=$( date -d "`date` - 61 days" "+%Y%m%d" | cut -b 5-8 )
if (( $e > 0 ))
        then
                tar --no-overwrite-dir -czvf backup_$f.tar.gz $d
                mv backup_$f.tar.gz /home/parthipan/test/logs_backup
                #rm -rf $d
                logger Data has been purged
```

The above script will be continued, with end of `fi` command.
It normally works on cli but not working on crontab. I have used logger command in last line so that the message will print in `/var/log`.
But the message printing is,

```
May  1 00:50:01 parthipan-nadar systemd: Started Session 24 of user root.
```

After that no other log forms. but the required log should be `Data has been purged`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say "but it is not working", can you specify _how_ it is not working? Is it simply not run, or is it run (and how do you know that) but there is an error?

Comment: Although you tagged your question `bash`, remember that cron likely uses `/bin/sh` - so if your script uses any non-POSIX features it may behave differently when sourced from cron compared to when you source it from your interactive shell

Comment: Why do you need to `source` the script instead of running it like `bash purging.sh`?

Comment: Does your script have a shebang (#! /bin/bash) as the first line?

Comment: steeldriver , you are right but my question is what can i do now ? is there any way to run the script in crontab ?

Comment: glenn jackman, But where shall i use this command in cli or in crontab ? By the way i tried it on cli it is throwing an error as invalid command.

Comment: You do NOT need to source a script just because it contains a cd. You would only need to source it if you wanted to have the cd effective in the level above. In this case, that is cron itself, and it does not care about directory. No cd on cli, no cd in crontab. Just in the script itself, and as many times as you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's working when you source it in your shell because you appear to be using your `ll` alias in the script. Scripts executing from cron do not have your environment, so you need to be more explicit about setting the `PATH` (if you're calling executables that live outside of `/bin` or `/usr/bin`) and not relying on your specific aliases or environment variables. If your  `ll` alias is an alias for `ls -l`, then use `ls -l` instead (but see the first point below).

Some other comments:

- [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you need to filter files based on age, use `stat` or `find`.
- You don't need to nest a date call within a date call: use `-d "60 days ago"`
- Don't call date 6 times (!!) just to get the year month and day:

  ```bsh
  read -r year month day < <(date -d "60 days ago" "+%Y %m %d")
  ```
- Use descriptive variable names. `a` `b` `c` ... are bad.

Comment: Thanx for correcting me but one problem remain the same even after doing the changes, and that is cd command. If we have to use cd command in the script then we have to source the  script before running it. This is actually creating problem!!! and I have used cd command due to frequently changing in the folders. I have 2020 folder in that I have 01,02...12 folder and in 01 I have 01,02.....31 . Actually this is the basic format. In which i have to take the backup and remove the file.

Comment: And you don't show any code in your question about how you use cd.

Comment: sorry brother, Now i have modified my question

Comment: Your statement is COMPLETELY UNTRUE: "If we have to use cd command in the script then we have to source the script before running it".